How to code this kind of graph in python using networkx?
I would like to create a graph where the first node is node 0, then there are 2 parameters n and l.
n represents the degree of the node, l the number of layers.
After the first node 0, this node should be linked to n different nodes, this is layer 1.
Then each of those nodes should be linked with n-1 different and distinct nodes so it has a degree n (this is layer 2) and so on.
The last layer is made with nodes with degree 1 since they are connected just with their parents nodes.
I would like to code this in python using networkx, ideas/suggestions/solutions ?
I have tried with for loops:

import networkx as nx
l = 3
n = 3
G=nx.Graph()

G.add_node(0)
max = 0

for i in range(l):
    for j in range (max,n+max):
      G.add_edge(i,j+1)
      if max <= j :
        max = j


nx.draw_networkx(G)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

In the image provided: we see the case for n=3 and l =2 this is the expected result for larger n and l the code fails, I would like to obtain a general algorithm that provide the right graph for all n and l, for example here if we add an extra layer each leaf of this tree should be connected with other 2 new nodes, so node 9 should be connected to other 2 nodes, 8 as well same for 6,7,5 and 4 so the degree of the node 9 will be 3, the two nodes connected with 9 would have  degree 1
does not work

Let's restructure the problem from a zero-index, to make it a bit more Pythonic.
Your root node is layer 0, node 0: 0-0.  It is connected to 3 nodes (degree of 3) in layer 1, nodes: 1-0, 1-1, and 1-2.  Each of these nodes are connected to a total of 2 nodes, the first being node 0-0, and then one other node in layer 2.  Each of the nodes in layer 2 already have degree 1, so we are done.
import networkx as nx
degree_start = 3
max_layers = 3

g = nx.Graph()
root = '0-0'
layer_nodes = [root]
is_root = True

for degree in range(degree_start, 0, -1):
    layer = degree_start - degree
    if layer > max_layers:
        break

    n = 0
    next_layer_nodes = []
    for node in layer_nodes:
        for i in range(degree - 1 + is_root):
            new_node = f'{layer+1}-{n+i}'
            print(f'{node} -> {new_node}')
            g.add_edge(node, new_node)
            next_layer_nodes.append(new_node)
            if is_root:
                is_root = False
        n += i + 1
    layer_nodes = next_layer_nodes


the code provided does not produce what asked, in fact there is the central node, is correctly connected to 3 nodes (n=3) each of this node is connected to just 1 node (should be connected with n-1 nodes a.k.a. 2 nodes)

That would mean ignoring the connection to the central node.  Your nodes 1, 2, and 3 all have degree = 3 in your picture, but you described them as having degree = 2, which is what I created.  If you want them to have degree 3, then each child node from the central node would ALSO have degree = 3.
